# The 'idnumbers' property on 'xxx' could not be set to a 'System.Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Int64'.

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-4, int64

I added a new attribute/column on my register form for an id number/social security number....... now bare in mind this is a 13 digit number and it gives me this error....... Please Assist.[My Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSg9Y.png)
[My DB Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUadp.jpg)

Comment: Don't post images of code, post your actual code please.

Answer (score -1):

Whilst it is a social security 'number', in this case it should probably be treated as a string.   Numbers are more suited to things you calculate with.   In your case it is a 'unique identifier' and you will never (for example), divide it by 2, or average several SSNs together (hopefully).